# AWS sdk for android: How to change the host end point

Tags: android, wasabi, aws-sdk-android

I'm using **Wasabi** for my file storage and I need to change the **AWS SDK** clients host url to that of wasabi. How can I do that?

```
AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new AWSCredentials() {
        @Override
        public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
            return accessKey;
        }
        @Override
        public String getAWSSecretKey() {
           return secretKey;
        }
});

/// Tried this but its not changing the endpoint and its still showing as aws s3 default endpoint.
s3client.setEndpoint(String.format("https://s3.wasabisys.com", Regions.US_EAST_1));
s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));



File fileToUpload = new File(filePath);
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest("ALPHA", "upload/" + 
fileToUpload.getName(), fileToUpload);

PutObjectResult putResponse = s3client.putObject(putRequest);
putResponse.getContentMd5();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the credentials like this,

```
    AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID");
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials, 
    Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_EAST_1));
    s3client.setEndpoint("ENDPOINT_S3");
```

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.8`

Comment: Is this the same sdk?

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN Yes I updated the SDK and updated the code too

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @KrishnakumarCN Nanni matram ullu alle :p

Comment: ida Ladu Lilefi kazhikku.... :p   (idu pazhaya lipi aayipoyi, pudiyadaayirunnel njan thakarthene ;-) )